# Replace text on click radio button and change it back to the original text if clicked on other radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html

String replace is working fine for me, But how to bring the last clicked radio button label text back to the original text?

```
function myFunction(id) {
    var str = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("{#var1#}", "<input type='text' name='var1' maxlength='30' size='30'>")
        .replace("{#var2#}", "<input type='text' name='var2' maxlength='30' size='30'>")
        .replace("{#var3#}", "<input type='text' name='var3' maxlength='30' size='30'>")
        .replace("{#var4#}", "<input type='text' name='var4' maxlength='30' size='30'>");
         document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = res;
}
```

Here is my PHP,HTML Code:

```
  <tr>
      <td><input onchange="myFunction('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')" type="radio" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" required></td>
      <td><b><?php echo  htmlspecialchars($row['template_name']);  ?></b></td>
      <td id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo  str_replace("\n","<br />",htmlspecialchars($row['template_content']));  ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: You forgot to open the <?php at the top of the second code block.

Comment: Its a part of my code not complete code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you help clarify what you're trying to do and what goes wrong?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? Is this even related to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add an extra attribute in the input instead (it can be `data-origin` or some thing like that). For example:

```
<input value="">
<div class="display" data-origin="xxxx"></div>
```

And then make a function trigger the change on the input:

```
$(input).onchange(() => {
    $(display).innerHtml = $(display).attr(data-origin)
});
//===continue your stuff====
```